# Shiro: Forcing second realm authentication even though existing session is already authenticated via other realm

Tags: java, guice, shiro

In my web application that uses Apache Shiro for AuthC and AuthZ I have two authentication realms: One for the regular web interface (called `SsoRealm`) and another one for the REST API (called `RestRealm`) using an API token. The principals authenticated by both realms have disjunct permissions (and `AuthenticationTokens`). If there is no pre-existing session and an API call arrives via the REST interface everything is fine and the authentication (and authorization) happens via the `RestRealm`. However, if there is an existing session previously authenticated via the
`SsoRealm` no authentication attempt via the `RestRealm` happens and the consecutive authorization check (using `Subject.isPermitted`) fails as the subject is from the wrong realm.

The corresponding authentication filters are registered as (using Shiro Guice):

```
addFilterChain("/api/x/*/y", REST_AUTH, NO_SESSION_CREATION);
addFilterChain("/**", SSO_AUTH);
```

Is there anything I can do to force a re-authentication with the "correct" realm?

Would a custom `AuthenticationStrategy` help (i.e., does the `AuthenticationStrategy` contract allow the implementation of a strategy "if `RestRealm` is involved, the `RestRealm` authentication needs to be successful")? AFAICS `ModularRealmAuthenticator.doMultiRealmAuthentication` is not called again if there is an existing authenticated session...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, this one was rather easy to solve: Just overwrite `AuthenticatingFilter#isAccessAllowed` to make sure that the 'right' principal type is authenticated for your realm (the default implementation just uses `Subject#isAuthenticated` to test whether any principal is authenticated - no matter whether it fits the realm or not).